# background-attachment:fixed not working in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I am developing a website in which I have used the `background-attachment:fixed`
property. It's working fine in Firefox, but the image is not fixed. In Chrome it's behaving normal. Here is code:

CSS:

```
.AboutBg
{
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-image: url("../Images/LandingPage/smart.jpg");
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 90%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="AboutBg"></div>
```

Answer (score 15):

I just had a similar issue, my cover + fixed was not working and images were disappearing on chrome and was able to solve it like this:

Crawl to higher node definitions and disable some of the CSS properties that may have conflicts, in my case for example, there was a:

`backface-visibility: hidden` at the `<body>` level that was causing it. This was being introduced by the animate.css framework.

Sorry its not a concrete answer but at least this provides some idea of how to debug your css code.

Comment: Yes, and thank you very very much, that was exactly the problem, and it solved it. Thank you.

Comment: I commented out `-webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;` in `class` of `.animated` and it solved the issue.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I can reproduce (in Chrome!) without 'higher node definitions': https://jsfiddle.net/sg1gzk3j/

Answer (score 2):

The Above Code should work with Chrome For Windows ,

Just try including the vendor prefix

```
-webkit-background-size: cover !important;
```

And give it a try

Comment: Thanks but now i got the answer ,i have set z-index:-1;

Comment: Setting Z-index to -1 fixed this issue for me as well.

Answer (score 2):

nothing was working for me, and finally this did the trick with no reasoning behind :)

```
-webkit-background-size: cover !important;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed !important;
position: static !important;
z-index: -1 !important;
```

This is working for me in both firefox and chrome. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is coming a  bit late, by adding the css style below seems to fix it for me.

```
html, body { 
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This fixed my problem:

```
.section{ position: static; }
```

(was `position: relative`)

Answer (score 1):

[@sabatino's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23931036/6266306) is right, but this will destroy the background-attachment:fixed bahavior in Firefox, because they also interpret -webkit prefixed properties - for whatever reason.

So you have to override it like this to make it work in both browsers:

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
-moz-transform: none;
```

Answer (score 0):

A late answer but I came around with this and somehow I made a hack for this one.

The idea was to create an inner element which will hold the background-image and will act same as `background-attachment:fixed` property.

Since this property makes the background image position relative to the window we have to move the inner element within it's container and this way we will get that effect.

```
var parallax_container = $(".parallax_container");
/*Create the background image holder*/
parallax_container.prepend("<div class='px_bg_holder'></div>");
$(".px_bg_holder").css({
    "background-image" : parallax_container.css("background-image"), /*Get the background image from parent*/
    "background-position" : "center center",
    "background-repeat" : "no-repeat",
    "background-size" : "cover",
    "position" : "absolute",
    "height" : $(window).height(), /*Make the element size same as window*/
    "width" : $(window).width()
});
/*We will remove the background at all*/
parallax_container.css("background","none");
parallax_container.css("overflow","hidden");/*Don't display the inner element out of it's parent*/
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var bg_pos = $(window).scrollTop() - $(".parallax_container").offset().top; /*Calculate the scrollTop of the inner element*/
    $(".px_bg_holder").css({
        "margin-top" : bg_pos+"px"
    });
});
$(window).resize(function(){
    $(".px_bg_holder").css({
        "height" : $(window).height(),
        "width" : $(window).width()
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about other people, but this worked for me:

`Z-index: -1`

Answer (score 0):

**With chrome 42**, background attachment was not working for me... until I close Dev Tools.

Hope this can save someone's time!

Answer (score 0):

bootstrap carousel was causing it for me.  Adding this CSS to reverse transition properties fixed it.

```
#carouselName .carousel-inner div.item.active {
  /* left: 0; */
  -webkit-transform: none;
  transform: none;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -webkit-perspective: none;
  -webkit-transform: none;
  -webkit-transition-delay: none;
  -webkit-transition-duration: none;
  -webkit-transition-property: none;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: none;
  backface-visibility: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `transform: translate3d();` is used anywhere on your website, `background-attachment: fixed;` will break in chrome. If possible, change all instances of `transform: translate3d();` to `transform: translate();`. This should fix your problem.