# Background img not showing on mobile version and it does on desktop "responsive mode"

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

I think i have messed up my code and I can't figure it out how to solve it.

This is the link of the web I'm doing: http://primerapropuesta.com.ar/Ashiwea2018/

If you go to id="map" section, you can see a parallax effect. If you switch the browser to responsive mode, you can see the same effect but with a different image.

That is exactly what I want to have on my site. But, if you open the same link on any phone, the background image does not appear.

PD: At first the image was the same for desktop and mobile and you could see it on any phone, but since i've changed the mobile image (using media property on css), both of them have stopped showing up.

If you guys need anything else to understand the problem, let me know and I will provide you with everything.

Thanks in advance!

PD2: Sorry if my english isn't perfect, my native language is spanish :)

Comment: Update: I made the parallax effect using the background-attachment: fixed;
If i delete that sentence from the css file, I can see the image on my phone. Could it be that parallax effect is not supported on phones? I have an iPhone 6s and tried on different browsers (safari, firefox and chrome)

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19028851/background-attachmentfixed-not-working-in-chrome and https://caniuse.com/#feat=background-attachment

Comment: Thanks a lot Dan! It was a compatibility issue.